# Pass variable from function to React return() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable from a function to my React return() function. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is:

```
class SaveOfferModal extends Component {

  toggleSuccess() {
    const { initialValues, formValues } = this.props;
    if (initialValues !== formValues) {
      const getChangedValues = diff(initialValues, formValues);
      const showChangedValues = JSON.stringify(getChangedValues, 0, 2);
      console.log(showChangedValues);
    }

    this.setState({
      success: !this.state.success
    });
  }

render() {
return ( 
        <Button
          color='success'
          onClick={this.toggleSuccess}
          disabled={isDisabled}
          className='saveOfferBtn'
        >
          Save Offer
        </Button>
)
}
```

Thanks! I'm trying to pass the getChangedValues variable to the return() function!

Comment: I think you can use `state` or `props` to do that when you are using React. Do as Romans do.

Comment: I don't know what is the exact thing that you want. In react way, you have three ways to passing value to render function: state, props, and by injecting variable from the outer scope. Hope this document can help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What's the variable that you need to pass to ```return()``` function

Comment: @DilanTharaka I'm trying to pass the getChangedValues variable to the return() function

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using state.
For example, if you have a count variable that you want to show in render

```
incrementCount() {
  this.setState((state) => {
    return {count: state.count + 1}
  });
}

handleSomething() {
  this.incrementCount();
  this.incrementCount();
  this.incrementCount();
}
render()
{
return ( 
        <Segment> The updated value of count is {this.state.count} </Segment>
)
}
```

You could also inject a variable from outside by using props.